# How to route from mixer to PC when using outboard equipment

Tags: mixer

Please let me explain how I've recorded in the past since I think this will make my question clearer.

```
Microphone -> direct into TL Audio pre-amp -> direct into soundcard.
```

This is the only way I know how to route.

Due to the location of my equipment (mixer - it's a home studio), the mixer could offer the ease of accessibility so I want to understand more.

Now, I know I could apply the following setup:

```
Microphone -> track 1 of mixer -> direct into TL Audio pre-amp -> direct into soundcard
```

But this doesn't seems like a good way, as it means that `Track 2` of the mixer cannot use the TL Audio pre-amp.

I was also given a patch bay if that matters (or not).

How do I set up my mixer so I can use the outboard device? In total, I have 3 outboard devices and sadly only 2 send/return on my mixer. I do have 6 AUX though! The problem is AUX is just a send.

This is where my head hurts.

Let's assume my TL Audio pre-amp is connected via `AUX 1`.

This would mean my AUX1 of the mixer goes into my SoundCard `Port 8` and my DirectOut on the mixer (of `Track 1`) goes into SoundCard `Port 1`. It then means Direct Out of `Track 2` of my mixer goes to SoundCard `Port 2` etc.

Is this correct?

Comment: What do you mean when you say: "one by the track output and another via the AUX"? WHat is the track output?

Comment: @EugeneS -I've updated my question, I hope this is now clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your question is not very clear, I will answer generally and then improve my answer if more information is supplied. First of all, it is important to mention that there are 2 types of audio effects:

1. **Parallel effects** -  used **with** the original signal, without changing it. For example if you use delay or reverb; your signal gets routed to the effect and then returned back to your mixing console. At this stage - you decide what will be the correct mix between the original signal and the effect.
2. **Serial effects** - affecting the **whole** signal, for example compression. Auxiliary channels in consoles are usually used to work with parallel effects. You send the original channel through aux to your effects processor and then route the processed signal(actual effect)  back to your return input.

I say that to imply that usually you will not use your auxiliary sends and returns to use them with external pre-amp. The signal has to be pre-amped before going into the mixer channel, long before it reaches aux send point.

Regarding your question about direct outs and aux returns - yes, both of them will output the same signal as long as the aux volume is at maximum since both of them are post-fader.

If you want to use your external pre-amp with your mixer, you can use the line-in input which, in most mixers, is skipping the built-in pre.

**EDIT1**:
In some mixers the aux send\return are utilized by only one insert point, however internally tip is used as send and ring as return. This is from your mixer spec:
[image]

Comment: I think your post suggests the AUX is a send and return, is that correct? Mine are only sends. I don't know how to return the signal.

Comment: Take a look at EDIT1

Comment: @daverook there is an answer [here](http://avp.stackexchange.com/a/6963/2569) that deals with send/return I/O

Comment: @Josh,  thank you for the link. I assume this means I must use a Y cable since my outboard had a send return.

Comment: @DaveRook, that is correct.